# How to use firebase auth in my own chrome extension

Tags: angular, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I would like to create simple chrome extension using angular. I create a homepage, where user can login by google account. It was easy, because I used AngularFire2. Problem occured, when I wanted use firebase in context menu of my own extension: f.e:

**context-menu.js**

```
var clickedFunc = function(info, tab) {
    console.log(info, tab)
    alert('click');
};

var parent = chrome.contextMenus
  .create(
    {
      "title": "check click",
      "contexts": ["selection"],
      "onclick": function(info, tab) {
        clickedFunc(info);
      }
    }
  );
```

These code work fine, but if I trying using firebase in my context menu in this way:

**context-menu.js**

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');

var config = {
  apiKey: 'secret',
  authDomain: 'secret', // you know what I mean
};

var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var clickedFunc = function(info, tab) {
    console.log(info, tab)
    alert(firebase.app().name);
};

var parent = chrome.contextMenus
  .create(
    {
      "title": "check click",
      "contexts": ["selection"],
      "onclick": function(info, tab) {
        clickedFunc(info);
      }
    }
  );
```

chrome extension was installed in my browser. **I can open homepage, but original context menu is not displaying. Anyone can help me?**

I added other part of other file, which can generate bug:

**part of manifest.json**

```
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["home.js", "context-menu.js", "firebase.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download firebase.js and put in in your extension, then load it with a relative url. Your extension isn't allowed to access external scripts.

Comment: I download firebase.js and added to extension in "scripts": ["home.js", "context-menu.js", "firebase.js"]. Do something wrong?

Comment: This was kind of buried, and not highlighted in the example provided by Chrome/Firebase...but here's the answer:

 Only popup operations (signInWithPopup and linkWithPopup) are
 available to Chrome extensions, as Chrome extensions cannot use HTTP
 redirects. You should call these methods from a background script
 rather than a browser action popup, as the authentication popup will
> cancel the browser action popup.

Comment: I added the Firebase stock code to my background.js page AND added firebase.js to the background scripts section of the manifest (firebase.js is packaged with the Extension).

    "background": {
     "scripts": ["/dscripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js","/dscripts/firebase.js","/scripts/background.js"]},

From [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login][1]

Comment: @SaravananNandhan If what you put in your comment is "the answer", then please edit your answer to reflect it. Preferably with links to that information.